# XMLimport of aria-label value

Tags: xml, parsing, google-sheets, xml-import

I'm blocking on some XMLimport I'm doing in a sheet.
So far, the data I've been looking at was quite easy to point at simply using chrome's `xpath copy` and a few tweaks.

But now, a chunk of what I need is behind a mouse-over on the website and I can't locate it.

From this website [wowprogress AF ranking](https://www.wowprogress.com/artifact_power/fr/)

For example, to get the correct value from that line concerning the character `Breakerkill" > "33` I used in Google sheet:

```
=importxml(A1; "//tr[2]/td[6]/span")
```

(the A1 cell is where I stored the URL for the sheet)

from that code

```
<span aria-label="45753 exp" class="hint--bottom-right innerLink" style="font-weight: bold;" xpath="1">33</span>
```

But now, for my next column, I need that node value `aria-label` (the "45753 exp" part) and I need assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there:

This should locate the value of the aria-label.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.wowprogress.com/artifact_power/fr/","//tr[2]/td[6]/span/@aria-label")
```

Let me know if that solves the problem.

I tried it and it produces this result:

```
46568 exp
```

Also, have a play with this or a similar tool https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html. It has lots of examples, including locating elements by attribute or finding the value of attributes. Then you can become a mini-expert on the subject!

Also beware of taking `Xpath` queries from the browser dev console. It works on the `DoM` and in loading the URL it may add missing tags like `<tbody>`. So if you try to use these queries on the URL contents - they won't work - at least without removing the extra selectors.

Comment: was this reply useful?